# Sorting audiobooks on Audible.com by release date when using Python requests library

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to reproduce the result of ["Scraping and Exploring the Entire English Audible Catalog"](https://towardsdatascience.com/scraping-and-exploring-the-entire-english-audible-catalog-ea279cd09f88) by Toby Manders to add results for the books released after this article was published. The idea is to take Manders' dataset and add equivalent fields for all the new audiobooks in the past year or so, and to do that with as few http requests to Audible as possible. I'm using a different Python library than Manders, and Audible has also changed a bit since that piece was published.

The approach used by Manders of getting paged results of each category views is working so far, but my http request is not sorting the result by release date. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://www.audible.com/search?pf_rd_p=7fe4387b-4762-42a8-8d9a-a63254c74bb2&pf_rd_r=C7ENYKDADHMCH4KY12D4&ref=a_search_l1_feature_five_browse-bin_6&feature_six_browse-bin=9178177011&pageSize=50'

r = requests.get(base_url)
html = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

# get category list, and links
cat_tuples = []
for cat in html.find('div', {'class':'categories'}).find_all('li', {'class':'bc-list-item'}):
    a = cat.find('a')
    mytuple = (a.text, 'https://audible.com' + a['href']+'&sort=pubdate-desc-rank')
    cat_tuples.append(mytuple)

# each tuple has a format like this ... ('Arts & Entertainment',
# 'https://audible.com/search?feature_six_browse-bin=9178177011&node=2226646011&pageSize=50&pf_rd_p=7fe4387b-4762-42a8-8d9a-a63254c74bb2&pf_rd_r=C7ENYKDADHMCH4KY12D4&ref=a_search_l1_feature_five_browse-bin_6&sort=pubdate-desc-rank')

#request first page of first category
r_page = requests.get(cat_tuples[0][1])
html_page = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

# results should start with '2Pac in the Studio' but instead it's 'Can't Hurt Me: Master Your Mind and Defy the Odds'
```

Adding `sort=pubdate-desc-rank` to the request URL appears to work in Chrome, but not with Python. I have tried changing the User Agent in my code as well, but that didn't work.

Note: I would describe Audible.com as generally unfriendly to scraping, but I don't see a clear prohibition against it. My interest in purely informational, and I do not seek to profit from gathering these results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a fresh look at my code this morning and discovered that the solution to this one is a silly coding error on my part. I'm leaving it up in case anyone else has a similar issue. These lines of code:

```
#request first page of first category
r_page = requests.get(cat_tuples[0][1])
html_page = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
```

Should be as follows:

```
#request first page of first category
r_page = requests.get(cat_tuples[0][1])
html_page = BeautifulSoup(r_page.text)
```